# Dolphin keeps opened files and folders in tabs

Tags: dolphin

I'm running:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
```

Dolphin keeps opened files and folders in tabs.

I really don't want it to do that!

I would like it to shut politely when I close it, and have no memory.

All advice welcome.

Answer (score 1):

With the default configuration dolphin will remember folders, tabs and window state from the last session. You can configure the startup behaviour, just click the hamburger icon (most right icon in the toolbar), chose `Configure` and then `Configure Dolphin` or use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> to open the `Configure Dolphin`-window, in this window chose `Startup` from the left side pane:
[image]